# Doctrine migrations diff throws MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mysql, docker, symfony

Running any database related command actually throws error:

> [2006] MySQL server has gone away

I am using docker and these are my `docker-compose.yaml` database and phpmyadmin configs:

```
...some services here...

  database:
    container_name: database
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: toma123
      MYSQL_DATABASE: api
    ports:
      - '4306:3306'
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: database
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: toma123
    ports:
      - '8081:80'

...some more services here...
```

Successfully accessing the phpmyadmin UI through browser. Can execute any `SQL`s in it so obviously have proper access. Not sure if I have to provide more information about the problem. Will edit the post if you need any. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this a number of times, and this is due to very low default setting of [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) in mysql.

What you can do is add customize mycustom.cnf to MySQL, increasing this value up to 8 or 16M.

```
   volumes:
     - <host path to>/mycustom.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/custom.cnf
```

mycustom.cnf like

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=16M
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_bin
transaction_isolation=READ-COMMITTED
```